# My app in test flight says beta testing expired. How do I update and reinstall my app?

Tags: ios, testflight, beta-testing

My app in App Store was in beta testing and it expired. My developer bailed. How can I update my app so that it can go back into beta testing in test flight? I can find latest build, but I don't know how to update and reload into test flight. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Just upload a new build, and distribute it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it expires after 90 days.  You have to change the version number and re-upload it.  In the project navigator in Xcode, click on the topmost entry (Often the name of your app), click on build settings in the center pane and scroll down to Versioning to increment the version number.  Set the active scheme to "generic iOS device" along the title bar just next to the app name & icon.  Then, from the Xcode toolbar, at the top of the screen, select Product->Archive.  Here's a tutorial that gives a lot of details. https://www.raywenderlich.com/5352-testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing